# Error with cv2.cvtcolor. Shows that src is empty

Tags: python, opencv

I am not an expert in python. When I run this code, I get an error stating that the source is empty. It occurs in the statement that converts bgr to rgb from a live video feed. I also attached some of the error code below. I did try to resolve it changing some of it, but it did not work out. So, if you have any ideas, please share.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode = False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findhands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img
                # for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                #     # print(id,lm)
                #     h, w, c = img.shape
                #     cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                #     print(id, cx, cy)
                #     # if id==4:
                #     cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmList

def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()

    while True:
        success,img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findhands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Error code is :

```
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1)
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This error happened because the image didn't load properly . So you have problem with the previous line cv2.imread my suggestion is :

1- check if the images exist in the path you give

2- check the count variable if he have valid number

Answer (score 0):

cap.read() probably failed to load the next frame. I can't say what the reason for that is, as the error does not specify that.
I would try adding this to your code

```
if not success:
    print("Frame couldn't be read")
    continue
```

after cap.read() and see if it successfully reads the frame, if not, take a look if everything is setup correctly, so that the frame can be read. Take a look at [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) and compare it to your code.
If it does read it correctly, then there might be an error, passing the frame to the function.